# About ℓ-adic and perverse stuff and ℓ-adic cohomology with compact support

Tags: lie-algebras, algebraic-groups, rt.representation-theory

Maybe this question is trivial.

We know from this paper at Inv. Math 1976 [(DOI link)](https://doi.org/10.1007/BF01390009), T. A. Springer constructed representation of the Weyl group $W$
on the cohomology of the Springer fibre. Also, Deligne-Lusztig constructed the linear representation of finite group of Lie type.

They all consider the $\ell$-adic field,
hence, I want to know why they must consider the field $\mathbb{Q}_{\ell}$,
and consider the  $\ell$-adic cohomology?
and if I want to study this theory, should I study the theory of $\ell$-adic fields?
and is the $\ell$-adic cohomology the basic tool in dealing these theories?

Comment: In the introduction of Milne's lecture notes on étale cohomology, he explained the motivations for étale (or $l$-adic) cohomology, including why the field $Q_l$ is necessary, and mentioned Deligne-Lusztig's theory as an application in the end. You may find it helpful.

Comment: I don't think you need to know much about $\ell$-adic fields, but it is probably a good idea to make yourself comfortable with locally constant sheaves.

Comment: @shenghao, Carnahan, thank you. I have got Milne's lecture from his homepage